# SQLAlchemy equivalent to SQL "LIKE" statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

A tags column has values like "apple banana orange" and "strawberry banana lemon". I want to find the SQLAlchemy equivalent statement to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE "%banana%";
```

What should I pass to `Class.query.filter()` to do this?

Comment: I found this link really helpful thought to share across. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_filter_operators.htm

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Each column has `like()` method, which can be used in `query.filter()`. Given a search string, add a `%` character on either side to search as a substring in both directions.

```
tag = request.form["tag"]
search = "%{}%".format(tag)
posts = Post.query.filter(Post.tags.like(search)).all()
```

Comment: Perfect!
Do you know if there's a better way to distinguish between apple and pineapple than adding a leading space?

Comment: Best way would be to just normalize your database and add 2 separate tables for tags and tag-to-task relations, and then use JOINs instead of LIKE.  Otherwise, yes, seems like you will have to have some kind of separator around each tag in the string. Leading space is not enough, since there is also pen and pencil, with %pen%. If you do something like "|apple|pineapple|pen|pencil|" and match "%|pen|%" it should not collide.

Comment: With normalizing, I'm not quite sure how I'll have more than one tag associated with a given task, or vice versa using the tag map. The "Toxi" solution appears to group the collection of tags as a single item, rather than storing each individually? And the method used in this (http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki/Recipes/TagCloud) recipe appears to only allow one tag per item.

What resources would be best for elucidating this topic? I've read this (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) too, but can't picture how to manage multiple tags.

Comment: As I said, you need two tables. Basically, its just typical Many-to-Many relation, so you can follow SQLAlchemy's guide on it: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship
 You will have `tags` table, where you store tag name and other tag info, and you will have `task_tags` table, which will have one record for each tag added to the task. So task with 2 tags will just have 2 records in `task_tags` table.

Comment: Is this safe from SQL-injections? I want to specify this as a user input

Comment: Does it work with a blob data type? My table column is encrypted but it won't work. However, if I just perform Post.query.filter(Post.title == 'My Title') it works.

Comment: @GaryOldfaber - I know this is some time later.. But 1) putting % at start and end is like doing a contains.. But 2) putting a % solely at the end is like doing a begins with, or 3) a % at the start is like doing an ends with .. So adapt the of use of % symbol to accommodate your requirements. I know this is some years later, but I hope this helps for any future readers.

Answer (score 16):

Adding to the above answer, whoever looks for a solution, you can also try 'match' operator instead of 'like'. Do not want to be biased but it perfectly worked for me in Postgresql.

```
Note.query.filter(Note.message.match("%somestr%")).all()
```

It inherits database functions such as **CONTAINS** and **MATCH**. However, it is not available in SQLite.

For more info go [Common Filter Operators](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.match)

Comment: What is the difference between these two operators?

Comment: @buhtz depends on your DB backend see SQL-Alchemy docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.match
In Postgres you get `to_tsquery` which lets you add text operators for things like `OR` and `AND` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES

Comment: FWIW: I found that `match` did not fully support partial string matches (eg `abc%` matching `abcd`) where `like` does.

Answer (score 15):

In case you want the case insensitive like clause implementation:

```
session.query(TableName).filter(TableName.colName.ilike(f'%{search_text}%')).all()
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this code:

```py
output = dbsession.query(<model_class>).filter(
    <model_class>.email.ilike("%" + <email> + "%")
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4/2.0:

```
q = session.query(User).filter(User.name.like('e%'))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use native sql, you can refer to my code, otherwise just ignore my answer.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE "%banana%";
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

bar_tags = "banana"

# '%' attention to spaces
query_sql = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%' :bar_tags '%'"""

# db is sqlalchemy session object
tags_res_list = db.execute(text(query_sql), {"bar_tags": bar_tags}).fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain the `LIKE '%' :bar_tags '%'`syntax ? That's wired.

Comment: This doesn't work, at least in SQLA 1.4 with sqlite or postgresql+psycopg2; the quoted % characters cause syntax errors.

Comment: Same for sqla 1.2, doesn't work.

Comment: I think some punctuation characters may have been eaten by SO. Use two vertical bars as string concatenation between the '%' and :bar_tags.

Answer (score 2):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325497) works fine, "The ORM Query object is a legacy construct as of SQLAlchemy 2.0" (ref: [Legacy
Query API - SQLAlchemy 2.0 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html)).

The corresponding SQLAlchemy v2.0 equivalent to the SQL `LIKE` statement using the `select` construct is as shown in the python 3.10 code snippet below:

```py
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

...

def get_multi_like_tag_substring_bidirectional(
    db: Session,
    *,
    tags_search_substring: str,
    skip: int = 0,
    limit: int = 10,
) -> List[Post]:
    return db.scalars(
        select(Post)
        .where(Post.tags.like(f"%{tags_search_substring}%"))
        .offset(skip)
        .limit(limit)
    ).all()

...

banana_tagged_posts = get_multi_like_tag_substring_bidirectional(
    db=db_session,
    tags_search_substring = "banana"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious

```py
select(User).where(User.name.like(f'%{some_term}%'))
```

SQLAlchemy provides some other methods of generating a `LIKE` clause.

- [startswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.startswith): search term followed by % wildcard

```py
select(User.name).where(User.name.startswith('A'))
```

```sql
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.name LIKE :name_1 || '%')
```

- [endswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.endswith): search term preceded by % wildcard

```py
select(User.name).where(User.name.endswith('e'))
```

```sql
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.name LIKE '%' || :name_1)
```

- [contains](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.contains): search term inside % wildcards

```py
select(User.name).where(User.name.contains('i'))
```

```sql
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.name LIKE '%' || :name_1 || '%')
```

Like the [like](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.like) and [ilike](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.ilike) methods, each of these has a case-insensitive counterpart: [istartswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.istartswith), [iendswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.iendswith) and [icontains](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.icontains).

---

*All these methods are available on core table columns too, and also work with the legacy `session.query` syntax.*

Answer (score 0):

Using PostgreSQL `like` ([see accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325497/10009545)) somehow didn't work for me **although cases matched**, but [`ilike`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.ilike) (case **i**nsensisitive **like**) does.

Comment: `ILIKE` is the case-insensitive version of `LIKE`, so your inputs differed only in case.

Answer (score 0):

What I've been using all these years:

```
model = MyModel
col = "name_of_my_column"
value = "your-value"

query = model.query.filter(getattr(model, col).like("%{}%".format(value))).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, I am adding leading and trailing space to the `tags` column so that i can match on the desired tag surrounded by space to ensure that only the full words are matched preventing 'pineapple' to match 'apple' or 'sqlachemy' to match 'sql':

```py
tag = 'banana'
search = f"% {tag} %"  # !spaces around the tag
query = select(MyTable).filter((' ' + MyTable.tags + ' ').like(search))
```

Answer (score -3):

Doing it like this worked for me (Oracle) as native sql

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%' || :bar_tags || '%' "
```