# Using function of sqlalchemy.sql multiple times in query

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy version 0.7.8. I have come across an issue where my user can search a text in plain english but record in db can have special characters between text. So if user enters "**please come early to the hospital**" and in db i have "**please, come early, to the hospital.**" then my query must return exactly **please, come early, to the hospital.**

i have found this easy solution.

```
needle = func.replace(func.replace(Message.text, ',', ''), '.', '')
Message.query.filter(needle==query_term.strip()).one()
```

But problem with this is that there can be many special characters in db like "**! ; : ? &**" etc and needle will look very inefficient so please suggest me any efficient solution to avoid repeating func.replace function.

I cannot find same question on stackoverflow let me know if someone has already answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all replies. I am able to improve it through this way.

```
IGNORE_CHARS = [',', '.', '!', '&', ';', ':', '@']
needle = build_replace_func(IGNORE_CHARS, Message.text)
record = Message.query.filter(needle == query_term.strip()).one()

def build_replace_func(chars, attr, replace_with=''):
    for character in chars:
        attr = func.replace(attr, character, replace_with)
    return attr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a query with [RegEx](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

There are examples in the [SqlAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#the-query-object).

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325467/elixir-sqlalchemy-equivalent-to-sql-like-statement).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove all spacial character in python

```
>>> impore re
>>> string = "please, come early# to the@ hospital"
>>> cleanString = re.sub('\W+',' ', string )
>>> print cleanString
please come early to the hospital
```

store your text as a string in a variable and then run your query with this variable.