# Python SQLAlchemy and Postgres - How to search using substring in json value

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am aware I can easily query a JSON value using this example query:

```
r = Books.query.filter(
  Books.nameofjsonfield['key1', 'key2'].astext.cast(Unicode) == 'exact_string_to_compare'
).all()
```

But how do I search for datasets matching a substring of the JSON value?

Answer (score 0):

After converting the value to text it is a simple matter of [using `LIKE` one way or the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325467/sqlalchemy-equivalent-to-sql-like-statement), or any of the other fuzzier matching methods:

```
r = Books.query.\
    filter(Books.nameofjsonfield['key1', 'key2'].
           astext.
           cast(Unicode).
           contains('not_so_exact_string_to_find')).\
    all()
```