# Up to date syntax for querying a database with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

What is the correct and up-to-date syntax to query a database with flask-sqlalchemy?

I've been through
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/index.html
Posts in here.

According to the documentation in https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/

"You may see uses of Model.query to build queries. This is an older interface for queries that is considered legacy in SQLAlchemy. Prefer using db.session.execute(db.select(...)) instead."

So I'd like to know how to write a statement that will get a record where a column contains certain keywords with the current most up to date syntax.

Something like this (which does not work):

`post_search = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).where(Post.content == form.search)).scalar()`

EDit:

My search function:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post_search = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).where(Post.content.like(form.search.data))).scalar()
        print(post_search.content)
        return render_template('search.html', form=form, search=post_search)
```

The model:

```
class Post(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "posts"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
content = db.Column(db.Text(1000), nullable=False)
date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

The record contains in the content field the value
"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."

I want to search that field for the value "Pellentesque" and get the entire record back.

The reason why [SQLAlchemy equivalent to SQL "LIKE" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325467/sqlalchemy-equivalent-to-sql-like-statement) dooes not answer my question is because I am looking for the up-to-date syntax according to flask-sqlalchemy. I provided the link above. The answer that was given to this person on that post is now outdated. I wasn't looking for a SQL translation. I just needed the proper syntax. Which @snakecharmerb already provided.

Comment: 1. What I expect is to obtain the correct syntax to perform a query to a database. in the db there is a table called "Post", with a field called "content". I want to retrieve a record that will contain a search string. 
2. I've tried syntax like the one already mentioned or "post_search = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).where(Post.content.like(form.search.data))).scalar()" but they all return "None". I am updating my post with the little code. That's what I've got.

Comment: For the `like`, you need to wrap the term with the `%` wild card, `db.session.scalars(select(Post).where(Post.content.like(f''%{form.search.data}%'))`

Comment: Thank you @snakecharnerb! This is what finally worked:
post_search = db.session.execute(db.select(Post).where(Post.content.like(f'%{form.search.data}%'))).scalar()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy equivalent to SQL "LIKE" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325467/sqlalchemy-equivalent-to-sql-like-statement) (specifically, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75982973/5320906)

Comment: I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77111773/5320906) to the duplicate candidate, which covers some other '`LIKE` options in SQLA.

Comment: Almost yes. If I am not mistaken this guy was looking for a "translation" from SQL to sqlalchemy. The syntax for flask-sqlalchemy is a tad different and I had no reference or examples to learn how to write my own statements with the latest "standards". This person was given a sqlalchemy queries as help that according to the official flask-sqlalchemy site or no longer to be used and we must switch to db.session.execute+stuff - TY for looking into this and the extra info